# ¿Cuantos métodos se recomiendan poner en una clase?

Tags: java

**Soy nuevo en java** y me gustaría saber la forma en que se organiza el código, la cantidad adecuada de métodos que debe de contener una clase:)

Ex. Si quiero hacer un programa que haga realice las 4 operaciones básicas (suma, resta, multiplicación, división), debería hacer una clase para cada operación e incluir su método, o... 
En una sola clase poner los 4 métodos...

Comment: Generalmente es un metodo get y un set por cada atributo, y los demás se pueden poner tantos como sean necesarios.

Comment: Puedes crear tantos métodos como quieras. En las clases que definen objetos,, se crean los métodos get y set para cada atributo además del constructor que también es un método. En clases que no definen objetos, puedes poner cualquier método. Lo importante es que pongas cada método en la clase que debe estar

Comment: Ese ejemplo es muy sencillo, ahí podrías hacer todo en una sola clase. Podrías hacer un método para cada operación o controlar todas con un sólo método.

Comment: Ni un constructor es obligatorio, ni los set y get. No hay reglas sino que aplicar el sentido común y recordar que es programación orientada a objetos.

Comment: obligatorio no es nada, pero es una "buena costumbre" hacerlo

Comment: ¿Es una buena costumbre dejar acceso libre a las propiedades de un objeto? ¿Generar código que no se va a usar es una buena práctica?

Comment: Una buena práctica es declarar los atributos como privados y acceder a ellos tanto para obtener su valor como para establecerlo a través de métodos públicos. Si no las vas a utilizar no crees el atributo ya que no le vas a poder asignar valor ni obtenerlo.

Comment: Buenas Mike, Siguiendo el hilo del compañero de arriba y completandolo, la respuesta es TODOS LOS QUE NECESITES!! y siempre seguir la dinamica que te pongo a continuación en negrita **un metodo solo tiene que hacer una cosa y si tiene que hacer varias cosas delega en otro metodo**. En principio hay que seguir la dinamica que C.Rodriguez te describio para realizar los metodos principales, esos metodos seran complejos y realizaran varias acciones, delega esas acciones en otros metodos y asi succesivamente. Sigue esa dinamica y aunque parezca sencilla mantener la filosofia es bastante compleja. E

Comment: Puede ser una propiedad cuyo valor se asigna en el constructor y a la que posteriormente solo se acceda en modo lectura, con un get, o una propiedad que se use internamente en el propio objeto y que no deba ser expuesta de ningún modo. Crear una propiedad como private y generar por defecto y en todos los casos los get/set es un claro ejemplo de código cuyo uso se ha pensado vagamente. Al fin y al cabo, en la práctica es igual a crear una clase y poner todos sus atributos como public.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71225/discussion-between-pablo-simon-diestefano-and-pablo).

Comment: Aunque como ya se ha dicho, puedes tener todas las clases que quieras. Pero para operaciones matemáticas como las que mencionas en el ejemplo, deberías tener una sola clase y si quieres, en este caso concreto podrías tener hasta un sólo método, en ese caso, tendrías que pasar al método los valores y el tipo de operación que quieres realizar y dentro del método, según el símbolo recibido, hacer la operación. Otra cosa que, creo, no se ha mencionado en ninguna de las respuestas, es el manejo de errores. Tus métodos deben saber capturar los errores, para que el código no falle...

Comment: ... por ejemplo, si al método `dividir` tú le pasas estos dos valores `(1,0)`, no puedes efectuar la operación sin verificar que el divisor es `>=0`, tendrás que levantar una `Exception` en ese caso, para que el programa no se rompa en tiempo de ejecución. Todo ese tipo de eventualidades son las que un programador debe tomar en cuenta para escribir un código robusto.

Comment: Aunque estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de Pablo y siempre tener en mente principle de SOLID cuando haces el codigo. Pablo ha explicado unos pero hay otros que puedes encontrar más información aqui: https://dzone.com/articles/the-solid-principles-in-real-life Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por el feedback @RaúlGarcia, en especial por el titulo Clean Code, se agrega a libros para leer este año

Answer (score 4):

No hay una regla estricta que te indique el número de métodos que debe contener una clase, pero para obtener un código flexible (abierto al cambio o a la extensión), deberías seguir ciertas directrices:

- Responsabilidad única: Modela tus clases para que sólo hagan una cosa, pero la hagan bien. Como dice el refrán, quien mucho abarca poco aprieta.
- Segregación de interfaces: Es mejor tener varias interfaces específicas que una de caracter general.
- Encapsulación: No muestres los atributos o la implementación de tus clases al exterior, generalmente lo importante para quien use esas clases es qué hacen y no cómo. Expón sólo los métodos necesarios para recibir o enviar la información necesaria.

Dicho esto, podrás encontrarte clases o interfaces que tienen un único método y otras que tienen cerca de 100, cumpliendo ambas estos principios. La interfaz Comparator, por ejemplo, tiene un método y la función que tiene es comparar dos objetos, decidiendo cuál "vale" más. En el otro extremo tienes clases como String, que también tiene una única función (manejar cadenas de caracteres -texto-) pero tiene unos 80 métodos para ello.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, mi panorama se amplio muchísimo!

Answer (score 3):

Saludos, Mike.

Basándonos en el famoso ejemplo de una **Persona**, esta llegaría a ser nuestra clase:

```
public class Persona {
    // Aquí va todo el código de la clase...
}
```

Una **Persona** (en la vida real) tiene diferentes y muchas características que la definen, en Java se conocen como **Atributos de clase**. Por ejemplo: nombre, edad, estatura, peso, etc...

```
public class Persona {
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    float estatura;
    // Aquí van muchos más atributos de clase...         

    // Aquí va todo el código de la clase...
}
```

Además, una **Persona** también puede realizar distintas y muchas actividades o acciones, en Java se conocen como **Métodos**. Por ejemplo: correr, saltar, hablar, etc...

```
public class Persona {
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    float estatura;
    // Aquí van muchos más atributos de clase...         

    public void correr() {
        // Realiza la acción de correr
    }

    public void saltar() {
        // Realiza la acción de saltar
    }

    public void hablar() {
        // Realiza la acción de hablar
    }

    // Aquí van más métodos
}
```

Básicamente, en una sóla clase, puedes agregar cuantos atributos y métodos te plazca, sin embargo, no siempre son todos necesarios, por ese motivo es mejor tener una idea de la clase antes de comenzar a escribirla.

Creo que esto es suficiente para tener una idea muy básica de cómo se organiza el código de una clase, pero mientras más investigues y avances aprenderás otras formas más complejas.

EDIT:

Con respecto a tu edición, eso depende de lo que quieras realizar, si solamente realizarás operaciones con dos dígitos y muy básicas, en una misma clase podrías agregar las 4 operaciones. Si en cambio, necesitas realizar operaciones más complejas, deberías pensar en mantener el código ordenado y separado. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public class OperacionesBasicas {

    public int sumar(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int restar(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    public int multiplicar(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    public float dividir(int a, int b) {
        return a / b;
    }

    // Aquí se pueden realizar más acciones...
}
```

PD: Al utilizar `int` o `float` después de `public` indicas que retornarás ese tipo de valor, eso llegaría a hacer como el resultado de la operación.

Comment: Sólo un detalle, deberían ser double y no int, al menos en la división. Buena respuesta.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano gracias, lo edité por float, pero podría ser double también. :)

Comment: si, un tipo de dato que tuviese decimales =)

Comment: ¿En tu concepción de la *realidad* sólo se suman, restan y multiplican enteros? ¿Y si quiero hacer cualquiera de esas operaciones con números `double`?

Comment: Saludos @A.Cedano, como mencioné en la publicación, todo depende de qué tan complejas serán las operaciones, en el ejemplo que adjunté, especifiqué: _"si solamente realizarás operaciones con dos dígitos y muy básicas, en una misma clase podrías agregar las 4 operaciones. Si en cambio, necesitas realizar operaciones más complejas, deberías pensar en mantener el código ordenado y separado"_. Esto último haciendo referencia a tener clases distintas si se requieren para realizar esas operaciones que mencionas (aunque inclusive pueden hacerse más métodos en la misma clase). Esto es sólo un ejemplo

Comment: Pero como mencionas, @A.Cedano, muy bien podrían utilizarse todos como `double`. Reitero, es solo un básico ejemplo para tener una idea muy básica, sin embargo, sabemos que la realidad es mucho más compleja.

Comment: @C. Rodriguez Ahora quedo mucho mas claro, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Una clase puede funcionar tanto con muchos elementos como con pocos. Una clase con pocos elementos es más clara que otra con muchos.

Una buena práctica es recurrir a la herencia. Si hay un procedimiento privado cuya única finalidad es servir de subrutina a otro, conviene construir una clase derivada y meter en ella a los dos.

Conviene que en la clase base sólo esté aquello que es necesario para el funcionamiento de esta y que aquellos elementos cuya función sea ser útiles en una aplicación de esta clase se encuentren en una clase derivada.

Answer (score 0):

Existen varios puntos para ello:

- Una clase java es un archivo de texto plano, asi que entre mas escribas mas KB ocupas, asi que dependera de la capacidad de tu disco duro.
- Una clase posee atributos que pueden ser pocos o muchos asociados a setter y getters para dar acceso a las mismas. Solo que no se pueden repetir.
- Asi como el constructor o los metodos, estos son parte de la clase y puedes declarar tanto como quieras pero con la salvedad que deben cumplir ciertos requerimientos:
- Para los metodos la diferencia se basa en si retornan o no algo, en la firma si esta sobrecargada o no, y si esta sobrecargada cuantos parametros existen y son distintos.
- Para los constructores, puedes colocar muchos a pesar de que tienen el mismo nombre debes modificar la firma, sobrecargarla o no y la cantidad de parametros que coloques asi como la combinacion de las mismas.